# Convert combination of string and object to object/array

Tags: php, api, yii2

I am using kennect apis. To handle invalid data, I use try(),catch. Now when I put invalid data, I print response in catch function.

As I am using kennect verdor, so I did below to handle exception.

```
    try
    {

    }
    catch (ApiException $e)
    {
        exit($e->getMessage(). PHP_EOL);
    }
```

And its exiting with below response,

> [400] Error connecting to the API
>   (https://api-int.kennect.com/v1/candidates) .stdClass Object (
>   [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] =>
>   400#address.postalCode?invalid [message] => invalid postalCode ) ) )

**Now**: I want to print response message from resonance.

I am getting response in `string`, so how can I get message part only.

**Note**: Below is `print_r($e->getMessage())` responce:

```
   [400] Error connecting to the API (https://api-int.kennect.com/v1/candidates) .stdClass Object
    (
    [errors] => Array
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 400#address.postalCode?invalid
                [message] => invalid postalCode
            )

     )

     )
```

Any php function/ other way to achieve this?

**Note**: I don't want to use `string parsing`, because result will might be different.

Comment: That doesn't looks like any error I've ever gotten from the Stripe Payments API And what does `kennect.com` have to do with Stripe, it uses `stripe.com`?

Comment: Use a regular expression to match everything before `.stdClass Object`

Comment: @Barmar these are kennect api.*

Comment: can i do it using php function ?? other than regex ?

Comment: What else could it be? You just want to extract part of a string based on a pattern. It's not like this is a standard format that would have a built-in function for parsing it.